# Who decides what is the memory address that the CGA video buffer will be mapped to?

Tags: hardware, ms-dos

In DOS, the memory mapped IO base address for the CGA video buffer is `0xB8000`. So when you write to `0xB8000`, you are actually writing to a buffer in the CGA card itself and not to RAM.

What I want to know is who decides what is the memory address that the CGA video buffer will be mapped to, does this information exists in the CGA card itself, and when DOS (or BIOS I don't know) scans to see what PCI devices exists on the PCI bus, it reads this information from the CGA card? Or is it only a convention to map the CGA video buffer to address `0xB8000`?

Comment: Related, but absolutely not a duplicate: [How did the IBM PC handle multiple physical devices serving memory at the same physical address?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2979/357)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

CGA pre-dates dynamic allocation of addresses in the PC world, by quite a few years. The video buffer appears at the area starting at 0xB8000 because the adapter responds to reads and writes at those addresses. Basically, when the CPU wants to read or write a value from or to a certain address, it places that address on its address bus (and asserts a given state using other pins); then any device which is also on the bus (memory, ROM, and cards on the [ISA bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Standard_Architecture)) can fulfill the request.

So the answer to your question is, it’s the CGA which decides that its video buffer appears at 0xB8000.

Comment: In the original IBM PC the BIOS figured out (prior to booting any OS) what video adapter (initially MDA or CGA) was installed, I suspect by checking memory locations and/or I/O ports for responses to indicate "card present". There were very few choices and, as part of the "IBM PC standard", one could argue that IBM made the decision as few people used a 3rd-party adapter that used different memory addresses, at least for basic compatible video modes. Even years later, plenty of software would simply check for the installed adapter type and make an assumption about the memory location.

Comment: @manassehkatz that doesn’t change the fact that the adapter chooses what address it responds on, not the BIOS. The BIOS does probe for MDA or CGA, but it doesn’t allocate addresses to the installed adapter.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt 1) So a device that is plugged into an ISA bus can't give away its address to a program, and the program must already know what the address of the device is (so this means that the address of the device must be fixed), correct?. 2) I think that a device plugged into a PCI bus can give away its address to a program, and its address can be changed each time the computer is turned on, is this true?

Comment: A device on the ISA bus has a fixed address, yes, or one of a few (hardware-selectable using jumpers typically, later software-selectable using plug-and-play). Software usually has to be told where to find a configurable adapter (see *e.g.* the `BLASTER` environment variable); for ROMs there’s an explicit protocol which allows them to be found during boot. PCI is software-configurable; the allocation algorithms are deterministic though so the addresses typically won’t vary from one boot to the next, unless hardware is added or removed.

Comment: @StephenKitt - In theory a video card could be memory mapped anywhere (or at least anywhere > 640k). In practice,if  you manufactured a CGA or MDA compatible card but used a different default base memory address, plenty of software (admittedly poorly designed) would break. The IBM defaults became "standard" pretty quickly as even business applications quickly moved to direct video memory access for performance reasons.

Comment: @manassehkatz *"In the original IBM PC the BIOS figured out"* is not correct. On the original IBM PC, the installed video adapter was indicated with jumper settings on the main board. The BIOS didn't start figuring it out or probing until several generations later. I agree you are otherwise correct about the address of the video adapter boards being defined by the IBM technical specifications. They designed the video boards, too, so the argument between you and Stephen seems like splitting hairs.

Comment: The initial IBM BIOS didn't search for expansion ROM cards (according to the 1981 technical reference listing) but by the time of the  1983 technical reference it's documented as searching for a AA 55 pattern in ROM with a size indicator, the ROM then needs to checksum to 0 in which case the BIOS will call it allowing hooking of various features.

Comment: @manassehkatz my point is that it’s the *hardware* that decides where it appears on the address bus, not the software. You can build a card that appears anywhere you want (including overlapping addresses, although fun ensues), the card decides. Compatibility is another issue entirely of course.

Comment: @CodyGray Agreed - hardware really decides. The original PC isn't like the last several generations where BIOS settings can be configured by the user. But whether by checking switch or jumper settings or a soft-probe of memory locations, what I meant initially was the the BIOS figures it out (and can then provide the information to the OS) rather than the OS figuring it out.

Comment: @manassehkatz ah right, so your point is that if software used the BDA to find out what segment to use for video (and available modes etc.), then other standards could have been used, correct? (Although I don’t think there’s a pointer to video RAM in the BDA, just to the current page.) Likewise if software used INT 0x10 instead of writing to video memory directly...

Comment: @PeterI: Most display cards for the PC, including the CGA and MDA, won't be usable until the display controller settings are set to yield a usable frame rate.  The original BIOS included code to initialize the CGA and MDA, but IBM recognized that future display adapters would need to be initialized in ways that the present BIOS couldn't know anything about.  The ROM search was added to allow display adapters to include their own setup code.

Comment: @supercat True and I'm little bit surprised that IBM didn't include a ROM search. Certainly the Apple ][ with autostart ROMs did so it's an odd omission in the original PC ROM.

Comment: @PeterI: The Apple ][ used slot-based addressing; each slot had a 16-byte slot and a 256-byte slot.  For slot 1, 0xC080-0xC08F and 0xC100-0xC1FF, then 0xC090-0xC09F and 0xC200-0xC2FF, etc.  Giving each of five slots on the PC 64K of address space might have been workable, but would have caused some problems when machines started having 8 or more slots.  Using an I/O register to bank things in and out might have worked initially, but would have wreaked havoc on multi-tasking systems.

Comment: @supercat True but I was talking about the Autostart ROM  bootable device search which looks for Disk II id bytes (much as the later PC bios does to find hard disk controllers) It's not obvious why the PC designers didn't add the scanning code originally (I'm assuming it arrived with the XT). Deciding where in the address space any ROM appeared was probably best left with jumpers.

Comment: @PeterI: My recollection is that the PC originally did an auto-start ROM search for some addresses which were decoded to motherboard ROM sockets.  I vaguely recall one socket being available on the PC (the remainder being used for Cassette Basic) but even if a socket was empty I don't know whether that would have made that address space available for bus cards.

Comment: @supercat you can always check the original PC BIOS source code ;-).

Comment: @supercat I checked the original BIOS source code (the 81 tech ref is online at archive.org) and I couldn't see it but it's definitely in the 83 tech ref.

Answer (score 7):

CGA cards provide their own RAM to the address space. This memory lies in the hole between 640KB and 1MB. By convention, it was stated that the video memory (for CGA cards) would begin at segment B000 if the CGA card is being connected to a B/W monitor, and B800 if connected to a colour monitor. This way, two CGA cards would coexist in the same system, providing a means of multimonitor environment (text only for the monochrome monitor and graphics for the colour monitor in a typical CAD environment).

So it seems that the base memory location can be changed somehow. Actually, it is more flexible than that. In text video modes, scrolling text is a fast operation not because the CPU shifts blocks of memory to make room for new lines, but because the CPU changes the starting address of the video memory so that the user sees a new page of video memory. There were 4 pages of video memory for text on a basic 16KB CGA card using 80 columns mode, and 8 pages if using 40 columns mode. This was possible because the CGA (and subsequent compatible graphics cards) used the well known CRTC controller Motorola 6845, which provides registers to specify where in memory the video data should begin.

Comment: Are you sure that CGA configures itself for monochrome in this way? MDA appears at B0000, but I don’t think CGA can. You could have two display outputs by combining an MDA or Hercules card with CGA, EGA, VGA or greater, or in some cases with jumpered EGA or VGA cards which could be set up as MDA.

Comment: The CGA card is always at 0xB8000 regardless of whether it is connected to a composite monochrome or RGB color monitor.

Comment: Scrolling an entire screen of text could be a fast operation [a standard XT with CGA could scroll two lines/frame without snow using the proper software] but generally wasn't.  The reason CGA text scrolling isn't as slow as normal text output is that the BIOS blanks the screen and then moves display memory without having to wait for vertical or horizontal blanking intervals.  It's too bad that the CGA made the main CPU conflict with attribute fetches rather than character fetches; had it done the latter, scrolling of screen with a non-black background could have been much cleaner.

Comment: I think there's a bit of confusion here; CGA giving colour or "B/W" (truthfully, greyscale) output depends entirely on the connected screen, and some dip switches on the card / choice of video mode in software. It doesn't do anything to the memory addresses. What you're likely thinking of is CGA vs MDA, which is generally what IBM meant when they said a "color" or "monochrome" display... and the two cards were designed to be installed and operate alongside each other, e.g. with a high quality 80-col mono text screen flanked by a lower rez colour one, as part of a cheap 'n' cheerful CAD setup.

Answer (score 1):

It's a first generation, *first party* piece of primary hardware for the IBM PC, before anyone even started thinking about offering additional video adaptors for the platform. Video was laid out in the system specs as being addressible at a certain set of addresses depending on the type of adaptor - and, indeed, it's something you set up using DIP switches on the motherboard, picking between a limited set of options (IIRC... "Color", i.e. CGA; "Mono", i.e. MDA; "None", or "Other"... as well as "40" vs "80" column modes).

So, who decided it? Er... *IBM did*.