# Who set the 640K limit?

Tags: ibm-pc, memory-layout

We all know that "*640K should be enough for everyone*". But who actually set this limit? The quote is often attributed to Bill Gates, but it doesn't seem like a decision for an Operating System vendor to make. And does MS-DOS have some kind of 640K limit? Doesn't it just come from the hardware?

But maybe Bill Gates was consulted on the matter, perhaps? And if he was, ***by whom?***

I feel we need to establish a timeline of key decisions made in the IBM PC memory architecture. When did Microsoft become involved with the IBM PC design? Was the 8086 processor already designed?

As far as I know, **the 8086 has two magical addresses.** The first is the **beginning of vectors**, which is address zero. The vectors need to be mutable, so RAM must be attached to this address. Thus each 8086 system needs RAM at address zero, the beginning of address space.

The second magical address is the **Instruction Pointer reset value**, the location from where the 8086 starts execution. Since that boot firmware must be fixed, there must be ROM at that address. The end of memory space was chosen for this location, address 0xFFFF0 to be exact.

Was Microsoft involved in these two decisions, which must have been done at Intel? I find that hard to believe. Who at Intel chose these addresses? Was it Stephen P. Morse, the 8086 principal architect?

This leads to the biggest question at hand, **the 640K limit**. Who set it? Where does it come from? I know that EGA and VGA video cards have memory at that address, address 0xA0000 onwards. But didn't these cards come, like, a *decade* after the release of 8086 and the first version of IBM PC?

**So, *was* there a 640K limit in the original IBM PC?** Or did that come later? Was there something attached to the 0xA0000 address in the original PC? Some original video card that was used on the PC? Something else? Who designed that hardware and chose that it would use the memory at 0xA0000?

Having designed quite a few embedded computers already back in the days when external logic was always needed for address encoding, I can kind of see how it could have happened. In my imagination it's like *"Ok, I've got this RAM at zero and the BIOS eprom at 0xF0000 so where should I place the video RAM...? Hmm, somewhere near the end, I think, so I can expand the main RAM... but not at the very end so I can expand the video RAM too... let's put it a 0xA0000, it's a nice round figure... we can change it at the next PCB revision anyway... Ok, ship it."* But would it have happened like this?

Was there some early consencus on breaking the continuous memory address space at 0xA0000? Who chose it? Was it some clerk behind a typewriter, making history? Some engineers at a meeting, late for a lunch appointment?  Maybe some guy with a soldering iron or a wirewrap gun, hacking up the first prototype of... what?

We need to get to the bottom of this, **the world needs to know!**

Comment: From the horse's mouth, [Bill Gates: "I never said '640K should be enough for anybody!'"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/alt.folklore.computers/mpjS-h4jpD8/9DW_VQVLzpkJ). Another quote in there: "The 
IBM PC had 1 megabyte of logical address space. But 384K of this was assigned 
to special purposes, leaving 640K of memory available. That's where the 
now-infamous ``640K barrier'' came from"

Comment: It did lead to the other joke: “I need to run Word, where’s my 256 meg ram chip” about the time “bloatware” was being applied to how some wrote programs...

Comment: @Robill It wasn't that 384K (There was actually another 64K minus 16 bytes if you turned on bit 20 of the address bus.) was assigned to other purposes. By the '90s, a lot of that "upper memory" was put to use with EMM386! It was that DOS could only load an executable into a contiguous bloxk of memory, and IBM chose to start video memory at A0000h.

Comment: The "640k limit" (hole in contiguous RAM) was just 1 of a series of short-sighted, odd, and/or bad decisions involving the PC.  Others include a) IBM choosing 8086 family over 68000. b) IBM not buying MSDOS outright instead of allowing Microsoft to co-own and co-market it. c) Intel choosing to overlap memory pointers instead of normative flat memory pointers. d) Intel thinking it would be an important feature of the 8086 to be able to assemble 8085 code, complicating and probably limiting the chip. e) Intel not realizing that the 286 protected mode would benefit from a way to go back to real.

Comment: It probably goes without saying but Intel choose 20 bits for the address bus of the 8086, which constrained the address space to at most 1 megabyte.  Beyond the address pins, there are also limitations in the instruction set that assume a 20 bit address space (the mechanism of the segment registers).  Other constraints, such as IBM's board design, then shrank the potential RAM from there.

Comment: @RichF: The overlapping pointers were a good design for programs that didn't need to handle *individual* objects over 64K.  Every "linear" design I've seen on 16-bit platforms would require programs to either subdivide memory into 64K sections and ensure no object crossed a section boundary, or else add extra code for every access that could straddle a section boundary.  Effective coding often required having more than two uncommitted data segments, but the 8088 design was much better than the 80286 design.

Comment: @Rob As Ben Franklink used to say "Most quotes attributed to people on the internet are wrong".

Comment: @supercat You make a good "glass half full" argument in showing an effective use of overlapped pointers.  From my "glass half empty" perspective I see a system limited by 16-bit pointers, causing people to find work-arounds for problems which need not exist in the first place.  If Intel had not chosen to go with a design which would halve source-code compatibility with their 8-bit CPUs, then they could have gone with a flat memory model easily expandable to a 32-bit memory space at some point in the future.  Instead, they locked in a half-a**ed model still dependent on 64 kbyte ranges.

Comment: @RichF: Unless one has a 32-bit memory bus, working with 16-bit quantities is going to be faster than working with 32-bit quantities.  Splitting objects into a size that will allow offsets to be stored as 16 bits rather than 32 will thus improve performance even on a machine with a 32-bit linear address space.  On the other hand, when using something like the 68000, using 16-bit offsets will limit objects to 32767 bytes.  Limiting objects to 65520 bytes doesn't seem as limiting.  From a practical perspective, something like a text editor...

Comment: ...that stores each line as a separate object could use 16-bit indexing within each line while accommodating individual lines up to 65,520 bytes.  If the 8088 had included at least one more segment register (or perhaps--for programs whose combined DS and SS usage would be under 64K, included a mode which would use SS as the default segment for non-prefixed instructions using any addressing mode) and included load-segreg-immediate instructions, it would have been just about perfect.

Comment: @RichF: To be sure, think the 68000 architecture is nicer than the 8088/8086, but it needs a minimum 16-bit data bus to be practical and IBM wanted to use an 8-bit bus.

Comment: Somewhere I recall reading that Microsoft argued for the 640K limit, because IBM had originally proposed a 512K boundary (i.e., exactly half the address space).

Comment: For those thinking the 640 Kb barrier was the most stupid decision ever, please remember that this machine could ship with 16 kb of RAM (though you needed more to do things like Zork, that requires 48 kb).  It was only later that the limit got really problematic, and that only because the IBM PC was wildly more successful than anybody could ever have believed at launch time.

Comment: It may be worth knowing that the DEC Rainbow 100, which could be upgrade to 896K of memory andwhich ran MS-DOS MS-DOS can see all 896K.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

There was a 640K limit on the original IBM PC, but it was the result of IBM’s design decisions, and nothing to do with Microsoft: it’s the largest contiguous amount of memory which can be provided without eating into reserved areas of memory. The [IBM PC Technical Reference](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_ibmpcpc602renceAug81_17295874/page/n0) includes a system memory map (page 2-25):

[image: IBM PC system memory map]

which is detailed on subsequent pages: the system is supposed to provide between 16 and 64K of RAM on the motherboard, then up to 192K as expansion, with an additional 384K possible in the future (providing 640K RAM in total); then there’s a 16K reserved block, 112K for the video buffers (of which 16K at B0000 were used for MDA, 16K at B8000 for CGA in the IBM PC), followed by 192K reserved for a “memory expansion area”, then 16K reserved, and 48K for the base system ROM at F4000.

DOS itself isn’t limited to 640K. Any amount of RAM (within the 8086 memory model’s limitations, *i.e.* up to slightly over 1MiB) could be used. This was the case in some DOS-compatible computers: the [Tandy 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandy_2000) and [Apricot PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apricot_PC) provided up to 768K, the [DEC Rainbow 100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_100) and [Sirius Victor 9000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirius_Systems_Technology) provided up to 896K, and the [Siemens PC-D and PC-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siemens_PC-D) provided up to 1020K; the original SCP systems on which 86-DOS was developed [weren’t limited to 640K either](https://dosmandrivel.blogspot.com/2007/11/first-dos-machine.html), and Microsoft kept one for a long time because it was the only DOS system they had which could run their memory-intensive linker build. On PC-compatible systems with memory available at 640K, typically provided by a VGA adapter, drivers could be used to add the memory from 640K up to 736K to the memory pool, increasing the maximum runnable program size. (This worked fine for programs which only used colour text mode, or CGA graphics.) Additional memory available in separate areas above 640K could also be added as separate memory pools, but that didn’t help run larger programs.

Note that the 640K quote is likely apocryphal.

As to *why* this limit was chosen, I don’t have a definitive answer, but there are a number of factors to consider:

- the IBM PC wasn’t *designed* as a family of computers, at least not past the 8086 and 8088;
- 640K was huge compared to micro-computer memory sizes at the time, both in terms of program requirements and in terms of cost;
- the memory map was probably designed the way it was in order to provide a balanced set of expansion possibilities: a lot of memory, a decent amount of display buffers, and room for ROM expansion (in the IBM PC, there were no option ROMs; those appeared with the XT).

Comment: Ok, the final question now is who made this system memory map, and why are there separate "384K Memory Future Expansion" and "Expansion Memory 216KB" blocks? It looks like perhaps someone already had made a video card with a fixed address before this architecture diagram was drawn...?

Comment: Note the right-hand side of the diagram: the 216K block is within the ROM address space, so it’s intended as room for additional ROM, not RAM. There was no graphics adapter at A0000 when the IBM was designed; I suspect the designers thought that 128K would be a nice, safe amount of address space to set aside for video. (If one imagined future graphics with 4 bits per pixel at MDA resolutions, 128K would provide just enough room.)

Comment: Memory was used in 64KB/128KB chunks, both because 64KB were the chips available and probably to simplify electronics when design boards. What I do suspect: The first 512+128KB for RAM. The last 64KB for Internal ROMs, that was upgraded to 128KB shortly thereafter - ROM+BASIC. The 2 remaining 128 for for 4 expansion ROMs, 64KB on size. This last tidbit is easy to confirm digging a bit in XT BIOS listings.

Comment: And of course the RM Nimbus PC-186 is another example of a DOS-compatible machine that provided 960KiB of RAM (64KiB was reserved for the framebuffer).

Comment: @Rui 64K blocks are nice to reason about, but I’m not sure it was really the main factor in designing the memory map — for one, the base model had 16K RAM, and there was only 40K of ROM (which included BASIC); even the XT and AT only had 64K ROM (including BASIC). The XT BIOS listing shows that the option ROM scan checks for a signature every 2K, from C8000 to F4000 included, i.e. over a range which doesn’t map to 64K blocks.

Comment: @Rui I think the right-hand side of the diagram provides a reasonable explanation: 3/4 of the address space for read-write memory, including video buffers, and the rest for ROM; then 128K for video (perhaps for the reasons you give, although MDA and CGA used far less than that), leaving 640K RAM.

Comment: 64KB is the segment size of all x86 processors in Real Mode. That is, exactly 64KB is accessible in each of the 4 segments (code, data, stack, extra) at one time. For this reason, discrete memory areas are almost always limited to 64KB. This is why graphics mode 13h is 320x200 instead of the aspect-correct 320x240 (the latter would require 75KB). I suspect 40KB ROM was chosen to allow an extra 16KB chip which would fit together in 64KB and thus stay in the ROM's segment. This would allow near calls instead of far calls which would save memory as well as cycles.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yeah, the point is that I do remember the XT ROM search for extra cards hooks, each 64KB I think.

Comment: @Rui it does, but every 2K, not every 64K.

Comment: AFAIK, the original statement from Bill Gates in an interview was something like “*You can do … [to overcome the limitation], but I can’t imagine what to do with that much memory*”. It never tried to defend the limit and it never implied that no-one would ever need more memory.

Comment: @Artelius: Real-mode CPUs did not divide memory into rigid 64K chunks.  From their perspective, 0x08000-0x17FFF was a contiguous range just like 0x10000-0x1FFFF.  The PC's DMA controller, however, was only designed to handle 64K, and the system used a 4x4-bit register file chip to control the upper four address bits during operations on any of DMA channels.

Comment: The reason IBM was happy to place such limits is that the PC was never intended to become a dominant platform. It was intended for the home and very small business markets, and was definitely not intended to compete with the IBM System/32 and System/34. If you've never heard of those, it's because the PC killed them.

Comment: Wasn't the 8086 hard-limited to exactly 1MB of memory by virtue of having only 20 physical address lines?  I thought the "slightly over 1MB" was a feature of the 80286 and other CPUs with 21+ address lines.

Comment: @Mark it was indeed, but I was trying to make the point that DOS itself doesn’t have (quite) the same limits as the underlying platform (8086 and BIOS); by “8086 memory model” I meant the 16-byte segment + offset approach.

Answer (score 22):

Following up on the @StephenKitt answer:

CP/M put BIOS and BDOS code at the top of RAM, and IBM decided to copy that idea.  Just like with CP/M systems, the plan was to raise the start of reserved memory from A0000 (640KB) to a higher value once newer chips like the 80286 arrived.

This would have worked if end-user programmers like at Lotus obeyed MSFT's guidelines. However, they naturally wanted speed, and so wrote directly to memory addresses.

This, of course, meant that all old programs -- which people paid a *lot* of hard-earned money for -- would instantly break, and so the range A0000 to FFFFF got permanently baked into PCs.

Comment: Could you expand on how that would have worked in practice, assuming well-behaved software?

Comment: @StephenKitt Good question. I don't think there is an interrupt vector which returns, say, the start of video memory. INT 12h returns the amount of contiguous memory, in KB, starting from address 0, but presumably if less than 640KB of RAM is installed this will be smaller and not tell you where video memory begins.

Comment: @StephenKitt in CP/M there was a command (but I can't find it now, and never had to use it, since my KayPro came with 64KB) to adjust the base address where CP/M loaded the BIOS.  http://obsolescence.wixsite.com/obsolescence/cpm-internals "BDOS and CCP ... do not need any customisation - **other than the need for them to be relocated (shifted up or down in memory) if the size of total memory changes after a user forked out to buy another 16K of RAM, for instance.​**"  IBM PCs presumably would have received such a feature when the 80286 arrived.

Comment: @RonJohn CP/M supported that, yes, as did DOS in its own way; but expansion beyond 1MiB (+ HMA) required following development rules which were only published with the 286, so software couldn’t be written in an upwardly-compatible manner on the original IBM PC because the rules to do so weren’t known (nor was the architecture of the 286 when the PC was designed). Even if programmers followed all the “rules” (of which there weren’t many), their programs wouldn’t be able to use RAM above the HMA.

Comment: (With appropriate rules, it is possible to write real-mode programs which work fine in protected mode; Windows is proof of that.)

Comment: @Artelius The point is that software was "supposed" to use the services only via the BIOS/DOS system calls, and not address directly memory. However, people wanted faster software, there were BIOS lists, and soon Norton published their own books for the average Joe that did not had access to the BIOS listings.

Comment: But even if DOS software had only called BIOS and DOS services, it wouldn’t have been easy to run it in protected mode on a 286 because of all the segment arithmetic which was commonly indulged in.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: Unfortunately, the DOS routines for text output were more than an order of magnitude (factor of 10!) slower than optimized functions that wrote screen memory directly.  Users preferred programs that could draw a screen in under 1/10 second rather than taking more than a full second, and programmers can hardly be blamed for giving users the kind of performance they want.

Comment: @supercat I known, I was an early user and did my share on using and abusing undocumented stuff when programming. Nevertheless, the point is that it all escaped to IBM control in several angles.

Comment: Also, remember there was no such thing as plug and play, so things like video cards were designed to ONLY work at a fixed location within the 1st MB.  Some had physical DIL switches, but for most of them, they had no option to move around.  You couldn't add 2 CGA cards for example, but you could add both a monochrome (Hercules) and a CGA card, to have 2 screens because they would always appear in different address ranges.  (I wrote such a system in the early 90s).

Answer (score 6):

Hardware choice of the IBM engineers, when they put the graphic hardware from address A0000 upward. From a software point of view it was possible to overcome the 640KiB limit if there was memory mapped into the A0000-BFFFF range. On regular PC compatibles it was quite difficult to do but some exotic hardware were able to use that.
I personally used a hardware emulator based on a NEC-V30 CPU that was inserted in the Atari ST that made it compatible with a PC. It worked fantastically well and because the Atari had at least 1 MiB linear memory (mine had 2 MiB) it had memory in the A0000-AFFFF area. This allowed to have 704 KiB for MS-DOS instead of the usual 640 KiB (it was even possible to use the B0000-B7FFF area giving 736 KiB DOS memory, but that was annoying as it limited the graphics to CGA compatibility losing the MDA emulation and the 640x400 B&W Olivetti mode was also lost.).

So the limit was a hardware limit, not a MS-DOS limit (there were also incompatible PC's that had more than 640KiB like the Sirius 1 and the Apricots who had up to 896 KiB of memory under MS-DOS).